# How do I get yarn installed on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, elastic-beanstalk

Currently you can't install yarn using yum so there doesn't seem to be an easy way to create a config that installs it before asset pre-compilation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can customize packages that are installed and commands that are run on deploy with `.ebextensions`

For yarn, I created a file with the following commands which install a recent node version and yarn:

```
# .ebextensions/yarn.config
commands:
  01_install_node:
    command: |
      sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
      sudo yum -y install nodejs

  02_install_yarn:
    # don't run the command if yarn is already installed (file /usr/bin/yarn exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "Yarn not found, installing..."'
    command: |
      sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
      sudo yum -y install yarn
```

More Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Comment: thanks for that script. I've just fixed a missing single quote at the end of `test` line

Comment: See my answer if one would prefer use the `node` provided by platform to install the `yarn`: https://serverfault.com/a/1051810/304519

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the accepted answer, you can create `.ebextensions/some.config` to order EB instances to install yarn on the instance creation.  In current EB environment, I find following config to be more succinct and understandable:

```
# .ebextensions/some.config
commands:
  01_install_yarn:
    command: |
      set -e
      npm i -g yarn
      ln -s "$(npm bin --global)"/yarn /usr/bin/yarn
    test: "! yarn -v"
```

In fact, current EB ruby environment includes `node` binary available at `/usr/bin/node`, you can use that to install `yarn` via `npm`.